# No serializer defined for type: System.Management.Automation.PSObject in Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

this is my class

```
  [ProtoContract]
            internal class Powershellresults
            {
                internal Powershellresults()
                {
                }
                [ProtoMember(1)]
                public Collection<PSObject> PsObjects { get; set; }
                [ProtoMember(2)]
                public string Script { get; set; }
                [ProtoMember(3)]
                public string Viewname { get; set; }
            }
```

but i get No serializer defined for type: System.Management.Automation.PSObject 
when i try to serialize it

```
private byte[] SerializeResults(Powershellresults obj)
        {
            byte[] data;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
                data = ms.ToArray(); ;
            }
            return data;
        }
```

PsObject is part of System.Management.Automation

Can i get around this and actually serialize this collection?

UPDATE:
by adding to my serialization method

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(PSObject), true);
```

I can get it to serialize- but it loses most of it's fields once serialized
how do i get it to "clone" the original object so it keeps all of its fields and properties?

**EDIT**

I figured it out!
I thought to myself that Powershell had to be able to serialize it's objects, because you can poll remote machines - how else would it be able to send the PSObject between machines - which it does! (woohoo!!!!)

Well, i found an article that described this, and found my keyword [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psserializer_members%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX)

```
Collection<PSObject> PSCol = Powershell.Invoke(); 
string SerializedCollection = PSSerializer.Serialize(PSCol);
```

//serialization to XML done!

then Serialize the string using Protobuf-net or what ever...

Deserialization is a bit awkward but pretty straight forward
for deserialization use:
Use Protobuf to deserialize the string and then...

```
PSObject obj = PSSerializer.Deserialize(DeserializedString) as PSObject;

Collection<PSObject> DeserializedCollection = new Collection<PSObject>(((ArrayList)obj.ImmediateBaseObject).Cast<PSObject>().ToArray());
```

and thats it..

Comment: Does it work when replacing the `internal`s with `public`s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!
I thought to myself that Powershell had to be able to serialize it's objects, because you can poll remote machines - how else would it be able to send the PSObject between machines - which it does! (woohoo!!!!)

Well, i found an article that described this, and found my keyword [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psserializer_members%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX)

```
Collection<PSObject> PSCol = Powershell.Invoke(); 
string SerializedCollection = PSSerializer.Serialize(PSCol);
```

//serialization to XML done!

then Serialize the string using Protobuf-net or what ever...

Deserialization is a bit awkward but pretty straight forward
for deserialization use:
Use Protobuf to deserialize the string and then...

```
PSObject obj = PSSerializer.Deserialize(DeserializedString) as PSObject;

Collection<PSObject> DeserializedCollection = new Collection<PSObject>(((ArrayList)obj.ImmediateBaseObject).Cast<PSObject>().ToArray());
```

and thats it..

Answer (score 1):

`PSObject` is too vague to make a good serialization candidate (not least, it is a `dynamic` provider, etc); I strongly recommend that you construct a *well defined* DTO model, i.e.

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public Collection<SomeTypeThatYouOwn> Items {get;set;}
```

where `SomeTypeThatYouOwn` has meaningful properties etc. You can always convert to/from `SomeTypeThatYouOwn` close to the serialize/deserialize setp. `PSObject` is basically a property-bag, and that doesn't work well since protobuf doesn't include any metadata (you need to know the shape of the data in advance to deserialize it meaningfully).

Comment: Thats too bad, i have alot of scripts (that are created by end users) and i need the return data to be serialized over a socket.
do you know of any other way to do this

Comment: @AlekCarlsen I don't have a magic wand to wave at that, I'm afraid. *Something* could probably be done, but fundamentally `PSObject` kinda invents its own dynamic type system that is quite a long way away from the regular CLI type system.

Comment: I figured it out - reading the documentation on System.Management.Automation - but thanks anyway - great library btw (y)