# De-serializing (SharePoint) XML to PSObject and Performance

Tags: c#, xml, regex, powershell, sharepoint

Beloved **SO'ers**,

I have a server running Powershell to access SharePoint 2010 data via Web Services.  I have several PS Scripts doing business logic on SharePoint data.  *While this script works, my issue is **performance***.

- I'm omitting the annoying **`ows_`** prefix
- I've considered using an **`XMLDocument`** and **`SelectNodes`** but
  remember, this is no telling what fields will be provided so this has
  to be dynamic.
- I've tried to access [**`PSSerializer`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psserializer(v=vs.85).aspx) as
  [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811921/no-serializer-defined-for-type-system-management-automation-psobject-in-protobu) recommends but I don't have it.  Is it in PS 3.0?
- I'm searching for a multi-value field and turning that into an **`SPFieldLookupValueCollection`**
- The performance hit *appears* to be taking place during iteration of **`matches2.Matches`**

> It took around **45 seconds** to process **800** items and I believe this
>   method could be improved.

**SP2010XmlToPSObject.ps1**

```
param ([string]$xml)

#Handle empty result set
if($xml.IndexOf("ItemCount='0'") -ge 0){return @()}

#Load SharePoint DLL
$a = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$rows = @()
$matches = $xml | Select-String "(<z:row(?:.|\n|\r)*?(?:/>))" -AllMatches

$matches.Matches | %{
      $obj = New-Object PSObject
      $matches2 = $_.Value | Select-String "(?:ows_)(\w*)(?:=)(?:`")((.*?)(?:`"))" -AllMatches
      $matches2.Matches | % {
            #handle multi-value fields
            if($_.Groups[3].Value.IndexOf(";#") -gt -1){
                  #$a = @()
                  $o = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection $_.Groups[3].Value
                  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty $_.Groups[1].Value $o
            }
            else{
                  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty $_.Groups[1].Value $_.Groups[3].Value
            }
      }

      $rows += $obj
}

return $rows
```

p.s.  Sorry, looks like SO syntax highlighter didn't like powershell's escape (`) char.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there an open bug report on this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/573286/xml-serialization-of-psobject-is-not-possible

Comment: Hey, nice find...  any thoughts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811921/no-serializer-defined-for-type-system-management-automation-psobject-in-protobu

Comment: I think that's a V4 feature. I don't do much manual serialization, but for the times I do I find I'm getting to like JSON quite a bit.

Comment: Any bump on this is appreciated.  I wonder if the RegEx performance could be improved... although, that may not be where the performance hit is occurring the most.